# coding a bash in c: don't understand how to implement the pipes

Tags: c, bash

I have to code this function (for the university) that has to:

1. Call the system call `pipe()`
2. Calling `fcntl()` so the pipes' file descriptors will be closed by an exec
3. Redirect the output of the right_cmd on `pipes[1]`
4. Redirect the input of the left_cmd on `pipes[0]`

structs:

```
enum next_action {
    NA_QUIT,
    NA_CONTINUE
};

#define NO_REDIR (-1)

struct shell {
    struct var_table *vars;
    char **environment;
};

struct var_table {
    size_t len;
    size_t capacity;
    struct var *vars;
};

struct var {
   char *name;
   char *value;
};

struct node {
#ifdef DEBUG
   void (*dump_to_stdout)(const struct node * const this);
#endif /*#ifdef DEBUG */
   int (*are_redirections_ok)(const struct node * const this, int   ok_in_redir, int ok_out_redir);
   enum next_action (*execute)(const struct node * const this, struct shell  * const sh, int in_redir, int out_redir);
   void (*destroy)(struct node * const this);
   void *impl;
 };

struct pipe_impl {
    struct node *left_cmd;
    struct node *right_cmd;
};
```

new pipe node function:

```
 struct node *new_node_pipe(struct node * const left_cmd, struct node * const right_cmd) {
    struct node *n = new_node_empty();
    struct pipe_impl *impl;
    assert(left_cmd);
    assert(right_cmd);
#ifdef DEBUG
    n->dump_to_stdout = pipe_dump_to_stdout;
#endif /* #ifdef DEBUG */
    n->are_redirections_ok = pipe_are_redirections_ok;
    n->execute = pipe_execute;
    n->destroy = pipe_destroy;
    impl = n->impl = my_malloc(sizeof(struct pipe_impl));
    impl->left_cmd = left_cmd;
    impl->right_cmd = right_cmd;
    return n;
  }
```

the function that i have to do:

```
enum next_action pipe_execute(const struct node * const this, struct shell * const sh, int in_redir, int out_redir)
{
    int pipes[2];
    int i;
    struct pipe_impl *impl = this->impl;

    if(pipe(pipes)<0)
        fail_errno("can not create pipe\n");
    for(i=0;i<2;i++)
        if(fcntl(pipes[i],F_SETFD,FD_CLOEXEC)<0)
            fail_errno("fcntl error pipes\n");
  /* ?????????????
   ?????????????*/
    return NA_CONTINUE;
}
```

the problem is that i don't know how to do the point 3 and 4 :S
any advice? thank you very much:)

Answer (score 0):

from `man dup2`

> dup2()
>          The dup2() system call performs the same task as dup(), but instead
>          of using the lowest-numbered unused file descriptor, it uses the file
>          descriptor number specified in newfd.  If the file descriptor newfd
>          was previously open, it is silently closed before being reused.
>
> The steps of closing and reusing the file descriptor newfd are
>          performed atomically.  This is important, because trying to implement
>          equivalent functionality using close(2) and dup() would be subject to
>          race conditions, whereby newfd might be reused between the two steps.
>          Such reuse could happen because the main program is interrupted by a
>          signal handler that allocates a file descriptor, or because a
>          parallel thread allocates a file descriptor.
>
> Note the following points:
>
> - If oldfd is not a valid file descriptor, then the call fails, and
>           newfd is not closed.
> - If oldfd is a valid file descriptor, and newfd has the same value
>           as oldfd, then dup2() does nothing, and returns newfd.

maybe

```
if (dup2(pipes[1], out_redir) == -1) {
    /* Handle dup2() error */
}
if (dup2(pipes[0], in_redir) == -1) {
    /* Handle dup2() error */
};
```

Comment: thanks for the answer.. but the code does not work... : "error dup2() pipes[0]: Bad file descriptor"